# how do i get intrinsic, extrinsic matrix from calib.txt(P0 ~ P3) in KITTI 3d object dataset?

Tags: python, computer-vision, camera-calibration, kitti

i know calib_cam_to_cam.txt in kitti.
So i can use

"""
S_xx: 1x2 size of image xx before rectification
K_xx: 3x3 calibration matrix of camera xx before rectification
D_xx: 1x5 distortion vector of camera xx before rectification
R_xx: 3x3 rotation matrix of camera xx (extrinsic)
T_xx: 3x1 translation vector of camera xx (extrinsic)
S_rect_xx: 1x2 size of image xx after rectification
R_rect_xx: 3x3 rectifying rotation to make image planes co-planar
P_rect_xx: 3x4 projection matrix after rectification
"""

this information.

but i can't make Px in calib.txt using this information. (R_rect * K_xx * [R_xx|T_xx])
how do i get Px matrix?